# Корректная работа почты на сайте mail.php

Tags: php, email, sendmail

```
<?php

$adminemail="post-adress@mail.ru"; //email 

$name=$_POST['name'];  // получаем данные
$email=$_POST['email']; 
$subject=$_POST['subject']; 
$message=$_POST['message'];

$header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$header .= "From: Antwerp-Diamonds <Antwerp-diamonds@mail.ru>";

$msg="  // формируем сообщение
<b>Имя:</b> $name <br/>
<b>E-mail:</b> $email <br/>
<b>Заглавие:</b> $subject <br/>
<b>Сообщение:</b> $message <br/>
"; 

mail("$adminemail", "Сообщение от $name", "$msg", "$header"); // отправляем
if ($mail) {exit("Письмо успешно отправлено!");} // выводим сообщение
else {exit("Письмо успешно отправлено!");}

exit; 
?>
```

Должно отправлять письма на почту mail.ru. Работает через раз - не приходят письма. Заметил некую зависимость успешности отправки от того, что вводить в поля, но точно не уверен. Сам файл "mail.php" в кодировке UTF8.

Comment: Какой заголовок приходит от сервера mail.ru на письма которые не доставляются? Вебсервер свой конфигурировали для корректной рассылки писем? Есть ряд требований которые нужно выполнить для успешной доставки.

Comment: Не совсем понял " 
Какой заголовок приходит от сервера mail.ru на письма которые не доставляются? ". Письмо не доставляется на почту просто, а  после отправки всё равно выводится "Письмо успешно отправлено!".

Comment: Веб сервер никак не конфигурировал, не знаю как.

Comment: Тогда читайте мануалы как получить детальные сведения от почтовых серверов при рассылке и как настроить ваш сервер для рассылки. Или лучше воспользуйтесь услугами smtp сторонних компаний. Например https://mandrillapp.com или https://sendgrid.com/
Тарифы копеешные, письма дойдут и в спам не уйдут*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал вот такой рабочий вариант.

```
<?php

    /* base */
    $to = YOUR_POST@Mail.Ru;
    $project_name = 'PROJECT_NAME';
    $subject = "Contact_form";

    /* fields */
    $f_name = $_POST["name"];
    $f_phone = $_POST["phone"];
    $f_email = $_POST["email"];
    $f_message = $_POST["message"];

    /* msg */
    $message = '<html><body>';
    $message .=  '<table border="1" bgcolor="#F8F8F8" width="100%">';
    $message .= '<tr><td colspan="2" style="padding: 5px 10px; text-align:center;">Контакты</td></tr>';
    $message .= '<tr>
                    <td width="30%" style="padding: 5px 10px;">ФИО:</td>
                    <td style="padding: 4px 8px;">'.$f_name.'</td>
                </tr>';
    $message .= '<tr>
                    <td width="30%" style="padding: 5px 10px;">Телефон:</td>
                    <td style="padding: 4px 8px;">'.$f_phone.'</td>
                </tr>';
    $message .= '<tr>
                    <td width="30%" style="padding: 5px 10px;">Е-майл:</td>
                    <td style="padding: 4px 8px;">'.$f_email.'</td>
                </tr>';
    $message .= '<tr>
                    <td width="30%" style="padding: 5px 10px;">Сообщение:</td>
                    <td style="padding: 4px 8px;">'.$f_message.'</td>
                </tr>';
    $message .= '</table>';
    $message .= '</body></html>';

    /* header */
    $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n"; 
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $project_name . '<'. $subject . '>';

    if( mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ) ) {
        exit("Письмо отправлено!");
    }
    else {
        exit("Произошла ошибка!");
    }

?>
```